# How to load kendo observable data array from MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, observable, kendo-mvvm

I have the following kendo observable object:

```
var observable = kendo.observable({
    people: [
        { name: "John Doe" },
        { name: "Jane Doe" },
        { name: "Jimmy Doe" }
    ],
    products: [
        { name: "Table" },
        { name: "Chair" },
        { name: "Tomato" }
    ],
    animals: [
        { name: "Dog" },
        { name: "Cat" },
        { name: "Monkey" }
    ]
});
```

Can i make the inner collections load Json data directly from seperate controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to create a controller that returns a Json result. Make an ajax call to the controllers route and stuff the response into a variable. Then refer to that in your observable. It might look something like this on the front end:

```
$.ajax("mysite/getstuff").done(
    function(data){
       var observable = kendo.observable(data);
    });
```

In this case the getstuff method on the controller needs to return a JSON object containing all of the properties and arrays you need like this:

```
{
    people: [array of people],
    products: [array of products],
    animals: [array pf animals] //etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this will work for one inner collection at a time but what if i wanna get a bunch of them from different controllers? (ie. people, products, animals in the edit) do i really need to chain multiple ajax calls for this? i would assume that Kendo would have a more elegant way of doing this...

Comment: You can do this all from one ajax call if you need to, you just need to form up your JSON response so that it has all of the objects you need. You may need a controller just for this if you're mixing lots of types. kendo.observable() is a function taking one OLN object. Form your JSON response to be a single object with a property for people, products, animals, etc.